# Efficiently fetching information from .xml files and make them available to other methods

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

first I'm sorry if I mix up some terminology or overlooked some very obvious method, but I'm quite new in C# and OOP in general and this is my project I "self learn" c# with at the moment. That's why I will share larger parts of my code to hopefully iron out some unclarities.

I wan't to get information from an .xml file and use those information in various different methods. For this I found a solution which I implemented and works fine, but is kind of clunky.

I use this Method to read out everything I need from the XML:

```
 class ReadAndLoad
    {
        public List<CharacterAttributes> FetchAttributes(string userPath)
        {
            // Declare a new XML Document
            XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            // Try to open the XML file
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nNow Loading: {0}\n", userPath);
                XmlDoc.Load(userPath);
            }
            // Catch "File Not Found" errors
            catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No file found!");
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            // Catch Argument Exceptions
            catch (System.ArgumentException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid path detected!");
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }
            // Catach all other errors, and print them to console.
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An Exception has been caught:");
                Console.WriteLine(err);
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }

            // Declare the xpath for finding objects inside the XML file
            XmlNodeList XmlDocNodes = XmlDoc.SelectNodes("/character/attributes/attribute");

            // Define a new List, to store the objects we pull out of the XML
            List<CharacterAttributes> attributeList = new List<CharacterAttributes>();

            // Loop through the nodes, extracting Person information.
            // We can then define a person object and add it to the list.
            foreach (XmlNode node in XmlDocNodes)
            {
                int tempValue = int.Parse(node["totalvalue"].InnerText);
                CharacterAttributes obj = new CharacterAttributes(node["name"].InnerText, tempValue);
                attributeList.Add(obj);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < attributeList.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(attributeList[i].AttributeName);
                Console.WriteLine(attributeList[i].TotalValue);
            }
            return attributeList;
        }
```

Created a "Character class" that has all attributes in an constructor

```
class Character
{
    //Attribute Fields
    public int Body { get; set; }
    public int Agility { get; set; }
    public int Reaction { get; set; }
    public int Strength { get; set; }
    public int Willpower { get; set; }
    public int Logic { get; set; }
    public int Intuition { get; set; }
    public int Charisma { get; set; }
    public int Edge { get; set; }
    public int Essence { get; set; }
    public int Resonance { get; set; }
    public int Magic { get; set; }

    //Attribute Constructor
    public Character(int xmlBody, int xmlAgility, int xmlReaction, int xmlStrength, int xmlIntuition, int xmlCharisma, int xmlLogic, int xmlWillpower, int xmlEdge, int xmlMagic, int xmlResonance, int xmlEssence)
    {

        this.Body = xmlBody;
        this.Agility = xmlAgility;
        this.Reaction = xmlReaction;
        this.Strength = xmlStrength;
        this.Intuition = xmlIntuition;
        this.Charisma = xmlCharisma;
        this.Logic = xmlLogic;
        this.Willpower = xmlWillpower;
        this.Edge = xmlEdge;
        this.Essence = xmlEssence;
        this.Resonance = xmlResonance;
        this.Magic = xmlMagic;
    }
```

And to create a character I created this Method which takes the list provided by ReadAndLoad.FetchAttributes and feeds them in the constructor

```
class CreateCharacters
{
    public Character CreateCharacterFromXML(string userPath)
    {
        ReadAndLoad readAndLoad = new ReadAndLoad();

        List<CharacterAttributes> attributeList = new List<CharacterAttributes>();
        attributeList = readAndLoad.FetchAttributes(userPath);

        int bod = attributeList[0].TotalValue;
        int agi = attributeList[1].TotalValue;
        int rea = attributeList[2].TotalValue;
        int str = attributeList[3].TotalValue;
        int cha = attributeList[4].TotalValue;
        int intuition = attributeList[5].TotalValue;
        int log = attributeList[6].TotalValue;
        int wil = attributeList[7].TotalValue;
        int edg = attributeList[8].TotalValue;
        int mag = attributeList[9].TotalValue;
        int res = attributeList[11].TotalValue;
        int ess = attributeList[12].TotalValue;

        Character myCharacter = new Character(bod, agi, rea, str, cha, intuition, log, wil, edg, mag, res, ess);

        return myCharacter;
    }
}
```

I feel like there is a more elegant and efficient way to do this, which is easier to expand upon with more data from the same XML. Because at the moment if I would like to introduce some other data I would have to create a new ReadAndLoad Method, the new class for that information, expand the character class and constructor and add all that in the CreateCharacter Method.

Someone pointed me towards xml deserialization, but I wasn't able to make the examples given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=netcore-3.1) work (I tried deserialization from TextReader).

The xml I tried to deserialize / get information from doesn't provide a schema as url, because of that I don't really know how to deserialize it. Given below is the start of the xml.

After some searching I found the schema .xsd that probably gives me the correct schema.

Deserialisazion is sadly not possible at the moment because of an error in the .xsd I can't find.

The .xsd I try to use for deserialization references another .xsd which seems to contain errors, which leads to some elements not being declared.

InteliSense sadly doesn't provide any information regarding that error.

Comment: The keywords you're looking for is *Serialization* and *Deserialization*. C#/ .NET has built in multiple tools to serialize and deserialize your objects to XML. Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization)

Comment: Do you have a schema.  Sometimes the schema location is a URL on 2nd line of the XML.  You can use a browser and go to page and get the schema.  Then there are tools to convert the schema to c# classes.  Normally where there are issues of using XML Serialization the namespaces are not correct.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fast answer. Yeah I already tried to use Deserialization from Text reader as describes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=netcore-3.1), but I ran in a problem I don't know how to resolve.

There are XmlElement(Namespace) properties defined in the method and in the given example xml file, but  I don't have those in the xml I try to deserialize.

Comment: Does you xml have prefixes?  The prefixes have to match the namespace URL.  There is sometimes a namespace with no prefix and then you have to include this prefix in the classes.

Comment: At the moment I'm, trying the following:

since I found the .xsd schema I converted it to cs using the xsd.exe. This worked more or less fine. Now I got this whole thing mapped out but I'm a bit lost on how I can use this to get information from an provided .xml file.

Comment: Did you deserialize?  The deserialize method create an instance of the root class and all children.  So the parsed data is in the instance(s) of the class.

Comment: Yeah I'm back to square one right now.

My problem is the conversion from .xsd -> .cs did not work correctly because one element can't be found.
The character.xsd (which I try to convert) references the bonuses.xsd which I provide.

But xsd.exe keeps throwing the error that all ref=bonus groups in the .xsd are not declared and thus the schema can't be validated.

Deleting those references allow conversion, but prevents deserialization. (There was an error in my.xml). 

At the moment I'm unsure how to resolve that error.

Answer (score 0):

The super-simple way to do this is to copy an XML document to your clipboard and in a C# code file Paste XML as Classes:

[image]

Comment: Hey, ty for the tip.
But I want to load data from a different .xml each time I run the program.

All the xml files are created by the same program and should all be following the same schema, but as I described in a edit I can't deserialize the .xml files at the moment.

Your solution seems to be only viable if I want to load data from the same .xml everytime or am I mistaken in that regard?

Comment: No.  When you do that Visual Studio creates a class definition that you can use with an Xml Serializer to load any XML file that has the same structure as the one you used to Paste XML as Classes.

Comment: Ah I understand now, sadly the deserialisazion throws an Innter Exception "InvalidOperationException: <character xmlns="> was not expected. If I try to deserialize the xml that I pasted as Classes.